# Producer clientId=producer-2 Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: spring-kafka

I use SpringBoot as a consumer of Kafka, and the program accepts messages from Kafka, but the log contains the following information

`[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-2] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide the kafka and zookeeper's configuration and the code.

Comment: It means the broker is down or your configuration is incorrect - look further up the log for an INFO log where Kafka prints all the producer configuration - make sure the boot strap server configuration is correct.